# Null Reference Exception when Updating a Node Neo4jClient .NET

Tags: c#, .net, neo4jclient

I have created a method that takes in node properties and updates those proerties on a specified Node, but when it get to the code to do the update I get a `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Here is the code:

```
public NodeReference<EntityNode> GraphUpdateEntityNode(
                        NodeReference<EntityNode> nodeId,
                        string guid,
                        string type,
                        string name,
                        string dateTimeCreated,
                        string currentVersionDateTimeCreated,
                        int versionCount,
                        int currentVersion)
{
    var nodeRef = (NodeReference<EntityNode>)nodeId;

    GraphOperations graphOp = new GraphOperations();
    graphOp.GraphGetConnection();

    clientConnection.Update(nodeRef, node =>
    {
        node.GUID = guid;
        node.Type = type;
        node.Name = name;
        node.CurrentVersion = currentVersion;
        node.DateTimeCreated = dateTimeCreated;
        node.CurrentVersionDateTimeCreated = currentVersionDateTimeCreated;
        node.VersionCount = versionCount;
    });

    return nodeRef.Id;
}
```

What am I missing here? Do I have to get the reference for the node again by doing `var nodeRef = (NodeReference<EntityNode>)nodeId;` because Im already passing it in as a parameter for the method? And do I have to call my abstracted  `clientConnection.Connect` before I update the node?

Here is the GraphGetConnection() method:

```
GraphClient clientConnection;
public GraphClient GraphGetConnection()
        {
            GraphOperationsLogger.Trace("Entering GetConnection Method");

                clientConnection = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
                clientConnection.Connect();

            return clientConnection;
        }
```

Comment: I see more things that might throw the exception, which one is it? `nodeRef`, `graphOp` or `clientConnection`

Comment: Its the `clientConnection.Update()` which throws the error @Silvermind

Comment: So that means that `clientConnection` is null. Where do you create it?

Comment: in the same class as this method, Ill update the question quick.

Comment: @Silvermind I have updated the question with the `GraphGetConnection()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `clientConnection` you are instantiating is in another class called `GraphOperations`
While you might have a variable with the same name in this class it will not be assigned by the `GraphOperations` class.
Update your code to the following:

```
GraphOperations graphOp = new GraphOperations();
var clientConnection = graphOp.GraphGetConnection();
```

Which will create a scope variable, but if you want to assign it to the 'variable' in this class do the following without `var`:

```
clientConnection = graphOp.GraphGetConnection();
```